# Dynamically build and return a Python list in a C Python extension

Tags: python, cpython, cextension

I'm writing a [Python extension in C](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html), and I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically build and return a Python list using my extension.  I know how to build a list of predetermined size using [Py_BuildValue](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue).  Is there a way to create a list with Py_BuildValue then append items to that list? Is there a different, and better, alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `PyList_Append`, just like (modulo reference management and whatnot) you'd use `.append` in Python?

Looking at the [list API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html) docs may help as well.